# create a raw choice dataframe from summarised df

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a new dataframe from a "summarised" dataframe.
Here is a simplified example of my summarized df:

```
vehicle <- c("bike", "car", "bus")
size <- c(1,2,3)
color <- c("green", "red", "blue")
price <- c(100,200,10)
n <- c(3,2,1)

my.df <- data.frame(vehicle,size,color,price,n)

 my.df    
  vehicle size color price n
1    bike    1 green   100 3
2     car    2   red   200 2
3     bus    3  blue    10 1
```

Now, imagine that this data is summarized from peoples choices of vehicles. 
The number of times a vehicles has been choosen is represented under column n.
Now I would like to make a raw "choice data set", where a column of respondent id is added. The new column choice represents which alternative that has been choosen (representing the n column from my.df)

This I what I would like the new dataframe , my.new.df, to look like:

```
respondent <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,2.1,2.2,2.3,3.1,3.2,3.1,4.1,4.2,4.3,5.1,5.2,5.3,6.1,6.2,6.3)
vehicle.2 <- rep(vehicle,6)
size.2 <- rep(size,6)
color.2 <- rep(color,6)
price.2 <- rep(price,6)
choice <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0)

my.new.df <- data.frame(respondent, vehicle.2 ,size.2,color.2,price.2,choice)


 my.new.df
   respondent vehicle.2 size.2 color.2 price.2 choice
1         1.1      bike      1   green     100      0
2         1.2       car      2     red     200      0
3         1.3       bus      3    blue      10      1
4         2.1      bike      1   green     100      0
5         2.2       car      2     red     200      1
6         2.3       bus      3    blue      10      0
7         3.1      bike      1   green     100      1
8         3.2       car      2     red     200      0
9         3.1       bus      3    blue      10      0
10        4.1      bike      1   green     100      1
11        4.2       car      2     red     200      0
12        4.3       bus      3    blue      10      0
13        5.1      bike      1   green     100      0
14        5.2       car      2     red     200      1
15        5.3       bus      3    blue      10      0
16        6.1      bike      1   green     100      1
17        6.2       car      2     red     200      0
18        6.3       bus      3    blue      10      0
```

Would be greatful for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can for each row create a new `n * 3` data.frame and stick those together. We'll have to use `paste` to get you respondent id's (although I think they should just be `c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, ...)`).

```
my.df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%                                                  #we need to do this by row
  do( {
    d <- mutate(my.df, choice = as.numeric(vehicle == .$vehicle))#add choice column
    d[rep(seq_len(nrow(d)), .$n), ]                              #repeat n times
    } ) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%                                                  #drop the groups
  mutate(respondent = paste(rep(1 : (n() / 3), each = 3),        #add in the weird ids
                            rep(1:3, n() / 3),
                            sep = '.')) %>% 
  select(-n)                                                     #drop the n column
```

My result looks different, because yours appears to be built from the bottom up (i.e. you start with busses, even though `my.df` starts with bikes).

> ```
> # A tibble: 18 × 6
>    vehicle  size  color price choice respondent
>     <fctr> <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>  <dbl>      <chr>
> 1     bike     1  green   100      1        1.1
> 2      car     2    red   200      0        1.2
> 3      bus     3   blue    10      0        1.3
> 4     bike     1  green   100      1        2.1
> 5      car     2    red   200      0        2.2
> 6      bus     3   blue    10      0        2.3
> 7     bike     1  green   100      1        3.1
> 8      car     2    red   200      0        3.2
> 9      bus     3   blue    10      0        3.3
> 10    bike     1  green   100      0        4.1
> 11     car     2    red   200      1        4.2
> 12     bus     3   blue    10      0        4.3
> 13    bike     1  green   100      0        5.1
> 14     car     2    red   200      1        5.2
> 15     bus     3   blue    10      0        5.3
> 16    bike     1  green   100      0        6.1
> 17     car     2    red   200      0        6.2
> 18     bus     3   blue    10      1        6.3
> ```

Comment: Great, spot on! I'll try this on my real data, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Axeman's answer is great. Just another solution using `plyr`:

```
obs <- ddply(my.df,.(vehicle),function(df){df[rep(row.names(df),df$n),1:4]})
res <- adply(obs, 1, function(df) {
    data.frame(
      respondent = paste(rownames(df), 1:3, sep = '.'),
      my.df[,1:4],
      choice = as.numeric(my.df$vehicle == df$vehicle))})
```

You can get rid of `obs` by using `%>%` operator